# Webscraping from a specific non-unique tag

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have webpages that contain data like (below)

```
<span class="results_summary"><span class="label">Thesis Note: </span>For the degree of Executive Master in Consulting and Coaching for Change, XXXX, February 2018</span>    
<span class="results_summary"><span class="label">Bibliography/Index: </span>Includes bibliographical references</span><span class="results_summary"><span class="label">Abstract: </span>In today’s “attention economy”, self-awareness, ability to regulate one’s emotions, having the
    negative capability, improved focus and clarity of mind for better decision making stand out
    as crucial traits for effective leadership.
    Despite the scientific findings re-affirming the positive impact of the regular practice of
    mindfulness meditation on effectiveness, take-up rate of the concept for formal leadership &amp;
    talent development programs has been slow. What’s novel in this study is to experiment and
    explore possible underlying reasons for that and articulate on the viability of mindfulness rollout
    programs in leadership development context.
</span>
```

The problem is all the tags contain span class="results_summary" and span class="label" repetitively. I would need to extract the huge paragraph under "Abstract". I just tried the below but unable to proceed beyond.

```
t=soup.findAll('span',{'class':'label'})
```

Output:

```
<span class="label">Thesis Note: </span>
<span class="label">Bibliography/Index: </span>
<span class="label">Abstract: </span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.next_sibling`

**Ex:**

```
html = """<span class="results_summary"><span class="label">Thesis Note: </span>For the degree of Executive Master in Consulting and Coaching for Change, XXXX, February 2018</span>    
<span class="results_summary"><span class="label">Bibliography/Index: </span>Includes bibliographical references</span><span class="results_summary"><span class="label">Abstract: </span>In today’s “attention economy”, self-awareness, ability to regulate one’s emotions, having the
    negative capability, improved focus and clarity of mind for better decision making stand out
    as crucial traits for effective leadership.
    Despite the scientific findings re-affirming the positive impact of the regular practice of
    mindfulness meditation on effectiveness, take-up rate of the concept for formal leadership &amp;
    talent development programs has been slow. What’s novel in this study is to experiment and
    explore possible underlying reasons for that and articulate on the viability of mindfulness rollout
    programs in leadership development context.
</span>"""

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
for span in soup.findAll('span',{'class':'label'}):
    if "Abstract:" in span.text:
        print(span.next_sibling )
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using beautiful soup you can use regex.

```
import re

result = re.findall(r'<span class="label">Abstract: </span>(.[\s\S]*)</span>',html_text)
```

An assumption was made that `<span class="label">Abstract: </span>` will be unique in your `html_text` if this is not the case, find an unique pattern that retrieves the required data.

Comment: Your solution with RegEx looks scalable as it can be modified for other tags. But I get the error: "TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object." when I run it. I have hmtl_text as a BeautifulSoup type.. Can you please help.

Comment: Here html_text is raw html text that is retrieved from the crawl response. And also `re.findall()` can't parse a BeautifulSoup object, so no need to convert the raw html to BeautifulSoup type.

Answer (score 1):

```
val = """<span class="results_summary"><span class="label">Thesis Note: </span>For the degree of Executive Master in Consulting and Coaching for Change, XXXX, February 2018</span>    \n<span class="results_summary"><span class="label">Bibliography/Index: </span>Includes bibliographical references</span><span class="results_summary"><span class="label">Abstract: </span>In todays attention economy, self-awareness, ability to regulate ones emotions, having the\n    negative capability, improved focus and clarity of mind for better decision making stand out\n    as crucial traits for effective leadership.\n    Despite the scientific findings re-affirming the positive impact of the regular practice of\n    mindfulness meditation on effectiveness, take-up rate of the concept for formal leadership &amp;\n    talent development programs has been slow. Whats novel in this study is to experiment and\n    explore possible underlying reasons for that and articulate on the viability of mindfulness rollout\n    programs in leadership development context.\n</span>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(val, "html5lib").findAll('span', {'class': 'results_summary'})[2]

for span in soup.findAll('span'):                                                     
    span.unwrap()
print(soup.decode_contents())
```

Will remove the extra tags from the span, and then encode the content as a Python string

```
"""Abstract: In todays attention economy, self-awareness, ability to regulate ones emotions, having the
    negative capability, improved focus and clarity of mind for better decision making stand out
    as crucial traits for effective leadership.
    Despite the scientific findings re-affirming the positive impact of the regular practice of
    mindfulness meditation on effectiveness, take-up rate of the concept for formal leadership &amp;
    talent development programs has been slow. Whats novel in this study is to experiment and
    explore possible underlying reasons for that and articulate on the viability of mindfulness rollout
    programs in leadership development context."""
```